# Questions about data preprocessing for time series forecast

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, autocorrelation, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following time series that I would like to forecast using a Recurrent Neural Network.

You can download the csv file from my github [here](https://github.com/doogersPy/files/blob/main/Xt_d_0.3.csv)

[image]

The task I want to solve is the following

> Given a window of the last $n$ observation, forecast the next 2 values of the series.

In order to solve this task, I need first to determine the size of the window of past observations $n$. Moreover, I should check if the series is stationary.

I have performed some preliminary analysis of the time series (stationarity and PACF).

The Adfuller test returns

```
Test Statistic : -5.821063
P-value : 0.0
Number of observations : 71661
Number of lags : 62
Critical value 5% : -2.86158
Critical value 10% : -2.566791
Critical value 1% : -3.430441
```

from which I can assume that the series is stationary, or better that it is not not-stationary.

The partial autocorrelation plot returns instead

[image]

which seems to suggest that there is an autocorrelation till lag 18.

**Questions**

- The ADF test seems to suggest the series is stationary. However, from the plot of the series, you can see that after the time step 40000, the series diverges from its mean value for a long period of time. I assume this will pose some problems for training my Neural Network model. For example, there is a non-negligible number of outliers. Can there still be some seasonality component in the time series?
- What is the good practice to normalize the samples from such a series? For example, if I choose my training set from timestep = 0 to timestep = 40000, and I choose to standardize each sample using the mean and the standard deviation computed from the training set, all the standardized samples from the test set (from timestep = 40000) will not have $O(1)$ values. This makes me think that the Neural Network won't be able to predict such values.
- Is it reasonable to set $n=18$ given the results from the PACF plot?
- What are the necessary properties that a time series should have in order to be predictable?